# $httpInterceptor not triggering before bootstrapping

Tags: angularjs

**Currect Structure**

I'm Bootstrapping my angular application manually because I have to get some data before booting my angular app, which uses $http & injected it manually using:

```
var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
var $http = initInjector.get('$http');
```

& use $http to call api

I also have an http interceptor which uses $httpProvider to handle specific errors in app.config function.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpInterceptor');
```

**The Problem**

Consider the api call before bootstrapping, the http interceptor handling is not working. I think because the factory i'm passing the $httpProvider is not yet tied up & will be initialised after the bootstrapping is done.

**So Tell Me**

Should I handle error case manually for that particular http request(before bootstrapping) which I think would be redundant or Is there a way I can make tie the httpInterceptor work before bootstrapping.

What would be a better approach?

Comment: What kind of data do you need to retrieve before boot?

Comment: Does it matter ? I just have to use it everywhere throughuout in my app.. so need that data.

Comment: I ask because your approach appears a bit hacky to me.  To do as you suggest might require an additional hack to your initial hack.  I too have sufferred with needing data before angular bootstraps and I started going down a similar approach but it got very complicated very quickly.  I was trying to learn if your data needs were similar to mine.

Comment: @pgreen2 So the data gives me some constants that i inject in app values (app.values) before bootstrapping.. So is it wrong ? How did you tackle your problem?

Comment: That's what we were trying to do as well.  We needed user specific information.  The solution we are currently using is to have a dynamically generated javascript file that is user based that we ensure is called after angular that does nothing more than load constants: `angular.module('app').constant('PERMISSIONS', ['ADMIN']);`  As long as you don't use `defer` or `async` to load the javascript, then angular won't bootstrap until all of the javascript files are loaded.

Comment: I can't change the bootstrap.. I think this is fine.. Just wanted to know if I can put interceptor before bootstrap.. or handling in error callback seperately is fine..

Comment: @pgreen2 Also wanted to know if that $http throws a 500 how can i throw an html page Do i have to redirect to different url ?.. & should I bootstrap in that case ?

Comment: If a 500 is thrown, then the promise from `$http` will be rejected.  You can do whatever you like in the `catch` method.  Personally speaking, the server shouldn't throw a 500 because that implies a programming error.  So I wouldn't do much in the client other than inform the user something really bad happened.  But that is more of how your organization handles things.